# Log4Net internal debug Timestamp

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I am having intermittent problems with Log4net not logging and in other threads there is a suggestion to setup internal logging by

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

I have added this and it does work, which is great, but there is no timestamp. Is there a way I can have Timestamp on the internal logging. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and solved it simply in the Log4net sources.
See the log4net jira issue: [LOG4NET-630](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-630) and the log4net pull request linked in there.

With this log4net improvement you can configure in the Web.Config / App.Config what you want to see in the internal log4net Log as a log message prefix.
For example:

```html
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.LogMsgPrefixPattern" value="%date [%7processid][%3thread][%appdomain]"/>
</appSettings>
```

to get log4net internal trace messages like this:

```
2019-05-22 13:51:30,266 [ 5984][ 3][/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/sw-f-ch-dn-1-132029994898417032] log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
...
2019-05-22 13:51:30,322 [ 5984][ 3][/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/sw-f-ch-dn-1-132029994898417032] log4net: Adding appender named [LogFile] to logger [root]
```